# How to change an img src with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are other questions like this and I've tried following them I'm just not aware of what exactly I'm doing wrong. I've declared the `pic` variable as being linked to the image with the corresponding id of 'pic' and I've tried many different examples and trying to follow other questions like this but to no avail.

--- THE REAL QUESTION ----

I would like the image to change its src to another one that I have in my workspace with the click of a button.

HTML:

```
<img class="trans" id="pic" src="images/link_rouge.png" alt="" width="1000" height="333" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');

function rouge() {
    pic.src = "images/link_rouge.png";
}

function blue() {
    pic.src = "images/link_blue.png";
}
```

I know the functions already work with the buttons because they are affecting some divs on the page that change color the only things not changing are the images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *The `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method registers the specified listener on the EventTarget it's called on.*

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) over `button` elements to attach `click` events and bind your handler functions to those events.

```js
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');

function rouge() {
  pic.src = "http://www.projectvictorycosplay.com/images/zelda/Links/3198_render_link.png";
}

function blue() {
  pic.src = "http://bin.smwcentral.net/u/1944/Link%2BBlue%2BTP%2Bshrunk.png";
}
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', rouge);
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', blue);
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn1'>rouge</button>
<button id='btn2'>blue</button>
<br/>
<img class="trans" id="pic" src="http://www.projectvictorycosplay.com/images/zelda/Links/3198_render_link.png" alt="" width="1000" height="333" />
```

Comment: Your example ddin't work and im using an onclick.... to be fair I should have included the button html too

Comment: That's weird the first two times I tried it, it didn't work. But now it does alright ill try out yours

Comment: Turns out that the problem was that I was trying to change the .style.backgroundcolor of divs before I was changing the image. Don't know what kind of problem it was exactly but I did start to use you addEventListener and I do enjoy and will be using them instead of the onClick() method.

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance your page has not loaded before `pic` is set equal to `document.getElementById('pic');`.

You can use something like jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function (or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handler);`) to ensure your page is fully loaded before assigning the pic variable.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var pic = document.getElementById('pic');

    function rouge() {
        pic.src = "images/link_rouge.png";
    }

    function blue() {
        pic.src = "images/link_blue.png";
    } 
});
```

Note: You will need to pull the JQuery library into your project to use this method.  See [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Also, you can read [this post](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/running_your_code_at_the_right_time.htm) to learn a little more about HTML/JavaScript and page loading.

Comment: Did you pull in JQuery?  You will not be able to use the `$` and the document.ready method if you have not.

Comment: Try including this in your html. `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Turns out that the problem was that I was trying to change the .style.backgroundcolor of divs before I was changing the image. Don't know what kind of problem it was exactly. Thank you for the suggestions though.